# Google Analytics Page Title setup

Tags: android

All that `tracker.trackPageView(trackable.getSceneTitle());` does now is filling the first "Active page" column but I would better get use of both "Active page" and "Page Title" columns. Is it possible to set Page Title with GA framework ?

Thanks.